# Image retrieved from url not showing

Tags: php, image

I'm extracting and displaying data from openweathermap api but when I try to display the icon provided by the Owm it either shows me a blank box (and formats all the other info on the page) or it shows garbage values.

I have tried two,three methods but nothing seems to work.Can you tell me where I might be going wrong? Here is the code snippet.

```
foreach ($data->list[0]->weather as $weather)  {
    $icon=$weather->icon; //returns the icon code
    $url='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'.$icon.'.png';
    $imginfo = getimagesize($url);
    header("Content-Type: ".$imginfo ['mime']);
    //header("content-type: image/png");
    readfile($url);
    //echo file_get_contents($url);
    echo '<li>', $weather->description, '</li>';
}
```

Comment: You are using two different variable names. `$imginfo` and `$imageinfo`.

Comment: P.S. You can't really show description or even more than one image in this way. You probably want to use the <img> tag.

Comment: even if i remove the loop and try to display just one image (i corrected the variable name, thankyou ) it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post to your question what you want to achieve drown by hand for example in paint, also post your html, so we will be able to help you in correct way, Answers to your question can be many as it is unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to include/display external images(icons for different weather conditions) on my page. for example http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png

Comment: And what if you will just use `<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png" />` on your page html ? like: `echo '<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'.$icon.'.png" /><li>', $weather->description, '</li>';`

Comment: yeah this method works, with base64 encode and src formatting. Thankyou! :)